# MySQL: Remove all references to database

Tags: mysql, macos

While importing a dump into a newly created database, the server stopped with the classic `server has gone away` message. I know why this happened and the fact that it did occur isn't part of the problem. I've removed the database directory from `/usr/local/mysql/data/` and still mysqld will not start successfully, probably because of a log or init file.

The goal is to get this fixed without having to fully reinstall mysql.

MySQL err log:

```
InnoDB: Page checksum 1559794421, prior-to-4.0.14-form checksum 641317514
InnoDB: stored checksum 3364647797, prior-to-4.0.14-form stored checksum 641317514
InnoDB: Page lsn 16 1049927436, low 4 bytes of lsn at page end 1049927436
InnoDB: Page number (if stored to page already) 43379,
InnoDB: space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 0 3302
InnoDB: (index "some_index" of table "some_database"."some_table")
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 43379.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
InnoDB: error.
InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
```

MySQL version:

```
$ mysql --version
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.55, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

MySQL conf file:

```
$ cat /etc/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=128M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do a Force Recovery by this way :
[How to do a Force Recovery InnoDB](http://www.techiegyan.com/2009/10/27/database-page-corruption-on-disk-or-a-failed-file-read-mysql/)
Or a safer way to try recovering the table :
[Table Recovery after Database page corruption](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/)
I hope it will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to fix this issue, adding to my.cnf:
`innodb_force_recovery=1`